# Crafter CMS How can a field can be disabled/grayed out in edit mode?

Tags: crafter-cms

In Crafter 2.5.x.
Is there a way to have a dropdown to be selected just one and after selected go to read-only mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not out of the box.

To accomplish this, you'll need to change the dropdown control by adding a new `property`, something like `Read-write if empty` or `Read-only if not empty` or similar.

You'll then need to update `dropdown.js` to respect that field and allow the user to edit the field if the field is empty (meaning the XML element behind it is empty).